# How to make a function to geojson in codeigniter 4

Tags: json, codeigniter, geojson, codeigniter-4

This an example function in `Codeigniter 3`:

```php
public function geoJSON()
{
    $records = $this->example_model->getAll();
    $this->load->view('geojson', ['records'=>$records]);        
}
```

... but it doesn't work in Codeigniter 4. Why?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the issue.

Comment: What is `geojson`? Maybe you mean geo coordinates as json?

Comment: I have mysql data in the table like coordinates and other attributes, I will make it as geojson using php, then geojson is displayed to the map with javascript, in ci3 it works but in ci4 it doesn't work, how..

Answer (score 0):

Because Codeigniter 4 use PHP 7.0 ++ while above syntax supported up until in PHP 5.4
I think you need something like this

```
$records = $this->Model->getAll();
             $this->load->view('geojson', $data['records'] = $records);
```

OR even better

```
$data['records'] = $this->Model->getAll();
                 $this->load->view('geojson', $data);
```